# Back Key in Libgdx

Tags: java, android, input, libgdx

I want my game not to respond to back key on menu screen if player wants to exit so he has to click exit button to exit game

My `class MenuScreen implements GestureListener, InputProcessor` and has `stage` as I want to use `fling()` of `GestureListener` and `keyDown()` of `InputProcessor`

so I do this

`multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer(stage, new GestureDetector(this), this);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(false);`

but this does nothing

I also tried to do this in `keyDown()` instead of `show()`

```
    @Override
        public boolean keyDown(int keycode)
    {
    if(keycode == Input.Keys.BACK)
        Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(false);
return true;
    }
```

but also nothing happened

Comment: It would be helpful to other users of this site if you go back and accept good answers for your previous questions. People will be more interested in helping you as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your application to catch the back key instead of the OS, then you want to use `true` instead of `false` as argument of the `setCatchBackKey` method. [See also the documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html#setCatchBackKey-boolean-):

> Sets whether the BACK button on Android should be caught. This will prevent the app from being paused. Will have no effect on the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

As @Xoppa says, you're using false when you should be using true.

Also, it doesn't really make sense to call this code in response to a button being pressed, because it's a setting for how to respond to buttons. In fact, `keyDown` will never be called for the back button, since Libdgx isn't catching it. You should call it only one time, in `create()`.